# Using Nuget and log4net in one dll that is used across a number of solutions

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, log4net, nuget

I have a dll called General which uses log4net.  This dll is used in many other solutions.
I would like to use Nuget.  But if I add a nuget package for general to use, that package appears on whichever solution I am in.  But there are 12 different solutions that use general.   So it does not make sense that General's reference should point to a package in a speficic solution.  Am i missing something?  Trying to get the NuGet yumminess, but not feelig the love.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to package up 'General' as a Nuget package of its own.  That way you can declare the dependency on log4net and it will use the same log4net as all the other packages you use in each solution.  You can run your own Nuget server easily to host the packages you develop internally.

Comment: Hmm, hosting my own nuget server sounds like a whole new can of worms preventing me from getting my coding work complete.  I was hoping Nuget would make getting and using the latest nuget packages easy, not require me to learn a whole new system.

Comment: Here's a blog post that explains the process: http://www.marcusoft.net/2011/09/creating-local-nuget-repository-with.html  Setting up a local Nuget server is actually rather easy, or your could try http://www.myget.org/